# I accidentally made fun of a sin I committed. Is it kufr?

Tags: sin, kufr, pork

I accidentally ate pork and told my friends about it and they laughed at it and said “new times”. Then after another conversation they were laughing at me and I jokingly said “I eat pork now so it’s new times”, but I didn’t mean it. Is this kufr?

Comment: Why should everything we do or say be kufr?